# jQuery detecting changes on two elements using keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyup

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="target" placeholder="example.com">
    <input type="checkbox" name="http" id="http" value="http"> http://
</form>

<div id="possible-targets">
    <h4>Possible matches: </h4>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var target_value;

$(window).load(function () {

    $('#target').keyup(function () {
        target_value = $('#target').val();

        if (target_value == '') {
            $('#target-match').remove();
        } else if ($('#target-match').length == 0) {
            $('#possible-targets').append('<h4><span id="target-match">' + target_value + '</span></h4>');
        } else if ($('#target-match').length != 0) {
            $('#target-match').html(target_value);
        }

        if ($('#http').prop('checked')) {
            if ($('#target-match-h').length == 0) {
                $('#possible-targets').append('<h4><span id="target-match-h">http://' + target_value + '</span></h4>');
            } else {
                $('#target-match-h').html('http://' + target_value);
            }
        } else {
            $('#target-match-h').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h2Uw4/

Now when I start typing in the text input field I can see a live change in the `possible-targets` div, but when I click on the `http://` checkbox it still needs to type at least one more character in the text input field to make a live change and add another possible target.

I tried to use `keyup()` on both `#target` (the text input) and `#http` (the checkbox) but it didn't work:

```
$('#target, #http').keyup()
```

Comment: It is working fine, I tried it on chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function and pass it to event handlers.

*Example Code*

```
var yourFunc = function () {
       //Your code
};
$('#target').keyup(yourFunc);
$('#http').change(yourFunc);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ws7L/)

As per @DavidThomas comments you can also use

```
$('#target, #http').on('change keyup', yourFunc)
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/dz7LQ/)

Comment: I'd suggest a minor change: [`$('#target, #http').on('change keyup', yourFunc)`](http://jsfiddle.net/4ws7L/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  var target_value;

$(window).load( function() {

    $('#target').keyup(function() {

        target_value = $('#target').val();

        if(target_value == '') {
            $('#target-match').remove();
        } else if($('#target-match').length == 0) {
            $('#possible-targets').append('<h4><span id="target-match">' + target_value + '</span></h4>');
        } else if($('#target-match').length != 0) {
            $('#target-match').html(target_value);
        }

        if($('#http').prop('checked')) {

            if($('#target-match-h').length == 0) {
                $('#possible-targets').append('<h4><span id="target-match-h">http://' + target_value + '</span></h4>');
            } else {
                $('#target-match-h').html('http://' + target_value);
            }

        } else {
            $('#target-match-h').remove();
        }

    });
    $('#http').click(function(){
        if ($('#target').val() !== "")
        if (this.checked === true) {
            $('#possible-targets').html('<h4>Possible matches: </h4><h4><span id="target-match-h">http://' + target_value + '</span></h4>');
        } else {
            $('#possible-targets').html('<h4>Possible matches: </h4><h4><span id="target-match-h">' + target_value + '</span></h4>');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to execute the callback functionality when the checkbox's value is changed. 
please update the js as :

```
var target_value;

$(window).load( function() {

    $('#target').keyup(displayMatches);
    $('#http').change(displayMatches);

});    
function displayMatches() {

    target_value = $('#target').val();

    if(target_value == '') {
        $('#target-match').remove();
    } else if($('#target-match').length == 0) {
        $('#possible-targets').append('<h4><span id="target-match">' + target_value + '</span></h4>');
    } else if($('#target-match').length != 0) {
        $('#target-match').html(target_value);
    }

    if($('#http').prop('checked')) {

        if($('#target-match-h').length == 0) {
            $('#possible-targets').append('<h4><span id="target-match-h">http://' + target_value + '</span></h4>');
        } else {
            $('#target-match-h').html('http://' + target_value);
        }

    } else {
        $('#target-match-h').remove();
    }

}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Uw4/2/#update.)